# How to do if condition with matching keywords in file name in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How could I detect if the filename of current buffer or the opening file contains a keyword? or matching a regex in emacs?

I'd like to set styles for different c sources according to their filenames, such as

```
if <pathname contains "linux">
   c-set-style "linux"
else if <pathname contains "kernel">
   c-set-style "linux"
else
   c-set-style "free-group-style"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`buffer-file-name`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html) returns the name of the current buffer, or `nil` if the current buffer is not visiting a file.

The function [`string-match`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html) matches a regular expression against a string and returns the index of the start of the first match, or `nil` if there is no match.

So you can set the style based on the file name like this:

```
(require 'cl)

(defvar c-style-pattern-alist '(("linux" . "linux\\|kernel"))
   "Association list of pairs (STYLE . PATTERN) where STYLE is the C style to
be used in buffers whose file name matches the regular expression PATTERN.")

(defvar c-style-default "free-group-style"
   "Default C style for buffers whose file names do not match any of the
patterns in c-style-pattern-alist.")

(defun c-set-style-for-file-name ()
   "Set the C style based on the file name of the current buffer."
  (c-set-style
    (loop with file-name = (buffer-file-name)
          for (style . pattern) in c-style-pattern-alist
          when (string-match pattern file-name) return style
          finally return c-style-default)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'c-set-style-for-file-name)
```